# Find base for which $a+b = S$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $3$ numbers $a, b,$ and $S,$ find the base for which $a + b = S.$

for example, if $a = 3, b = 7$ and $S = 10,$ then answer will be $10$ because $3 + 7 = 10$ is true for decimal number system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each of $a, b, S,$ you can expand to $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}x^{i-1}$ with $n$ being the number of digits and $a_{i}$ being each digit from right to left. Solving for $x$ yields the base. For example: $a=3,b=7,S=10$ would give $$(3(1)) + (7(1)) = (1x + 0(1))$$
with the solution $x=10$

Another example would be $a=110, b=10, S=1000$
$$(1x^{2}+1x+0(1))+(1x+0(1))=(1x^{3}+0x^{2}+0x+0(1))$$
$$x^{2}+2x=x^{3}$$
$$x+2=x^{2}$$
So the original equation must be in base 2

(Note: this idea can be extended to non-integer variables quite easily)